# Hough transform

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

```
for(size_t i=0; i<lines.size(); i++){
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line(gray, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);    
}
```

I have this code here for using the Hough Transform function. May I just ask about this particular line:

```
line(gray, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
```

What does the Point(l[0], l[1]) and Point(l[2], l[3]) mean? Are these the two points constituting the line? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you should **read** it as it were saying:

```
line(gray, (start_point.x, start_point.y), (end_point.x, end_point.y), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
```